# Do I need to notify UKVI I've renewed my US passport?

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, us-citizens, uk-visa, passport

I've just moved to the UK on a Tier 1 Exceptional Promise visa. It's good for the next 5 years, but my US passport expires in a few months. Once I've renewed my US passport, do I need to notify UKVI, and if so, what is the appropriate way of notifying them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since the [Biometric Residence Permit must be replaced](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/biometric-residence-permit-replacement-service) when:

- your UK visa is in a passport that is lost, stolen, damaged, or **expired**

and the BRP is needed to prove your right to work or rent or you are travelling outside the UK.

The application can be applied for inside the above link, but only **from within the UK**.

In cases where the passport was lost or stolen **outside the UK**, a ‘replacement BRP visa’ can also be applied for in the above link which lets you re-enter the UK.
You must then apply for a replacement BRP within 1 month of your return to the UK.

Answer (score -2):

According to https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa you can use the visa in your expired passport to enter and leave the UK (you will need to carry both your expired passport with the visa, and the new passport).

You *cannot* use the visa in your expired passport to prove your entitlement to work.  For that, you need to apply for a Biometric Residence Permit (see https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/biometric-residence-permit-replacement-service).  This is yet another opportunity for you to give the UK government money.  Sorry.

So, to answer your question directly: you do not need to tell the UKVI you have replaced your US passport if you just want to visit the UK; if you want to work in the UK you will need to apply for BRP (and if asked why, say that your passport has been replaced).

Comment: Your answer does not directly address the question of whether it's necessary to notify UKVI about the new passport.  I would infer that it is not, but an explicit word or two would be a good addition to the answer.

Comment: @Martin Bonner How does the final sentence of your answer address the question?

Comment: @Traveller It helps the OP calibrate his expectations for when dealing with UKVI.

Comment: @Martin Bonner Well I guess nothing is free in this life - if there was no fee for services, tax payers would be picking up the bill.

Comment: @Traveller UK immigration fees are something like ten times higher than the costs of providing the services they cover.  Martin Bonner: this link seems more relevant to this case than the one in the answer: https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/replace-visa-brp

Comment: @phoog I appreciate that, and I don’t mean to sound unsympathetic. However AFAIK there is no legally binding rule that says government services of any country have to be provided at cost, and as with any commodity if the buyer doesn’t want to pay the fees associated with moving to a particular country they have the choice not to ‘buy’ from that country and choose to go to another instead. The only reason I’m engaging in these comments is that I don’t feel it’s appropriate for answers to include personal opinions. A reliable, factual answer is all that’s required.

Comment: @Traveller of course there's no legally binding rule like that.  That doesn't mean that people cannot or should not complain about exorbitant fees.  If answers shouldn't include personal opinions than this would be a rather boring endeavor.

Comment: @phoog Extra paragraph added to very directly answer question.